# How to preview a post in a Lemoon site

Tags: lemoon

When I hit Preview on a blog post I'm editing it acts as if I pressed "Save draft". It pops up a message at the screen top saying that the draft has been saved. I've tried multiple browsers. The URL I see when I hover over Save draft and Preview does appear to distinguish between the two (ctl00$content$savedraft vs. ctl00$content$preview).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, the preview button should open a new window with your draft. Have you checked if your browser blocks popups?

Comment: Thanks. I did turn off popup blockers in IE. Chrome is not acting like the popup is blocked... it actually confirms that a draft was saved as if I pressed "Save draft". Oh well.

Comment: The preview functionality should save a draft. The draft is then supposed to open in a new window. Sometimes it is a bit hard to know if Chrome blocks popups because the indicator is not very visible. I suggest you try allowing popups in Chrome as I suspect that is the problem.

Comment: Aha! That was it. The message that a draft was saved was leading me to believe that a preview was not even being attempted. I allowed popups in Chrome and now it works fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it works fine in IE11. I'm not sure why it's not working in Chrome for me, but IE is my primary browser anyway.